# How can I show 1000 as 1.000 in java spinner

Tags: java, swing, localization, number-formatting, jspinner

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JSpinner editor locale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035063/jspinner-editor-locale)

I have to show 1000 value as 1.000 in the spinner in java , by default it is showing as 1,000. But in European locale the number should be in 1.000,00 format instead of 1,000.00 . Can someone help me with this. I am using below code:

```
 JSpinner.NumberEditor editor = new JSpinner.NumberEditor(spinner, pattern);

 spinner.setEditor(editor);
```

and using pattern as `"##.##0"`, but this is throwing exception.
Can I write generic code for this which can take care of number format according to locale ie., en, fr, pt etc.?

Comment: There is not such thing like European locale. Each country in Europe is a individual deal so the do not share locale settings. ;-)

Comment: _by default it is showing as 1,000_ hmm ... normally, the format is localized implying that either the default locale on your machine _is_ a locale using the comma or your machine locale is not supported by the jdk. So the question is: What is your locale?

Comment: I am fetching data from the server, and server locale is french.

Comment: simply, what I need to do to get 1,000 as 1.000 in the spinner if we just forget locales for a moment.

Comment: you can't forget locales, that's the whole point :-) You want to format the values as appropriate to _a_ locale. So first you have to decide _which_ locale the ui should show up. Typically, that's the default of the client machine. If you want to show it in a different locale, you have to use a format/ter in that different locale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try creating or get the locale explicitly:

```
JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner();
String pattern = "0.000"; // valid format
JSpinner.NumberEditor editor = new JSpinner.NumberEditor(spinner, pattern);
DecimalFormat format = editor.getFormat();
Locale locale = new Locale("ru", "RU"); // create your specific locale
DecimalFormatSymbols decimalFormatSymbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols(locale);
format.setDecimalFormatSymbols(decimalFormatSymbols);
spinner.setEditor(editor);
```

Comment: the above code showing 1000 as 1000.000 in the spinner, I want 1000 as 1.000 , please provide the format to be used.

Comment: I guess it depends on the locale. Try define the format pattern so `pattern = "0,000";`. I hope you catch my idea